# With Newtonsoft.Json, on iOS not deserialize with culture invariant?

Tags: ios, json, xamarin, f#, json.net

I'm trying to read json with financial info like:

```
{"cost": 0.0, "price": 417.0, "total": 834.0, "doc_id": 2, "status": "Sync", "doc_code": "ORD-5-1", "doc_kind": "O", "username": "02", "createdat": "2019-01-02T17:09:48.478918", "sub_total": 834.0, "tax_value": 0.0, "updatedat": "2019-01-02T17:10:08.00777-05:00", "customer_code": "43915888_37", "delivery_order": 0, "discount_value": 0.0}
```

But it return, for example:

```
"cost": 0.0 //json
cost: 281474976710656 //.NET
```

This happened if the locale of the iOS device is set to Spanish/Colombia. On US locale it work. The weird thing is that is supposed to work with invariant culture:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Culture.htm

**This happened only on device**. *With emulator is fine*.

This is how I try:

```
module test.main

open System

open UIKit
open Foundation

let fromJson2T<'T> x = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'T>(x)

type DocumentRow = {
    doc_id:int32
    doc_kind:string
    doc_code:string
    customer_code:string
    from_code:string option
    username:string
    createdat:DateTime
    updatedat:DateTime
    dueat:DateTime option
    signature:string option
    authorized:string option
    delivery_order:int32
    price:decimal
    cost:decimal
    tax_value:decimal
    discount_value:decimal
    sub_total:decimal
    total:decimal
    status:string
    notes:string option
    syncdata:string option
    version:int32
}

let DOC = """
{"cost": 0.0, "price": 417.0, "total": 834.0, "doc_id": 2, "status": "Sync", "doc_code": "ORD-5-1", "doc_kind": "O", "username": "02", "createdat": "2019-01-02T17:09:48.478918", "sub_total": 834.0, "tax_value": 0.0, "updatedat": "2019-01-02T17:10:08.00777-05:00", "customer_code": "43915888_37", "delivery_order": 0, "discount_value": 0.0}
"""

[<Register ("AppDelegate")>]
type AppDelegate () =
    inherit UIApplicationDelegate ()

    override val Window = null with get, set

    // This method is invoked when the application is ready to run.
    override this.FinishedLaunching (app, options) =
        let row:DocumentRow = fromJson2T(DOC)
        printfn "%A" row
        true
```

I also try with

```
let jsonSettings = JsonSerializerSettings(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Culture= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

let fromJson2T<'T> x = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'T>(x, jsonSettings)
```

Using FSHarp.Core 4.5.4, on OSX, Xamarin.IOS  12.2.1.13, Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1.

P.D: I update the code sample, and verified is very easy to reproduce. I create a blank iOS project, put the code in the sample. Run on emulator, work, on device, not work. Both set on "(Spanish/USA)"

P.D 2: With https://github.com/vsapronov/FSharp.Json also happened. But parsing manually like with http://www.fssnip.net/8y/title/JSON-Parser (changing from float to decimal) work fine.

Comment: Hard to know what's going on here since Json.NET has its own `decimal` parsing code, [`ConvertUtils.DecimalTryParse()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ConvertUtils.cs#L1271), which doesn't appear to have any culture-dependent code.  What happens if you change `decimal` to `double` in `DocumentRow `?  Or if you just to `JToken.Parse()` using [`FloatParseHandling.Decimal`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_FloatParseHandling.htm) or `FloatParseHandling.Double`?

Comment: Also, are you using a custom build of Json.NET, or a standard build provided by Newtonsoft?

Comment: You might try forking a local copy of `ConvertUtils.DecimalTryParse()` and then running the unit tests from [`ConvertUtilsTests.DecimalTryParse()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/Utilities/ConvertUtilsTests.cs#L193) on the device, to see what happens.

Comment: I'm using a stand build, with Nuget.